# WCF Calling a service property from a callback without deadlock

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, deadlock

Can someone kindly show me how to call a property of a WCF service from within a callback without deadlock occurring?

I've tried adding [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] to the class which implements the callback, but without success.

The service has the following attribute:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

public class SAPUploadService :    ISAPUploadService
{
```

Thanks MM

Here's the code which calls the Callback method

```
        foreach (var otherConnection in _users.Keys)
        {

            SAPUploadInstruction ins = AddMessageToInstruction(message);
            ins.UserName = user.UserName;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                otherConnection.ReceiveInstruction(ins);
            });
```

and here's the callback implementation of the ReceiveInstruction

```
public void ReceiveInstruction(SAPUploadInstruction instruction)
        {
            // fire this objects call back....
            if (OnReceiveInstruction != null) OnReceiveInstruction(this, instruction);
        }
```

In the above, the event OnReceiveInstruction is attached to the UI. This is handled as follows:

```
 public void ReceiveInstruction(object sender, SAPUploadInstruction instruction)
        {
             DispatchIfNecessary(() => {
                 ProcessInstruction(instruction);
                        });
        }
```

The method above - ProcessInstruction - sets various controls according to the service properties/functions. It is this that is getting deadlocked i.e Label1.Content = myService.SomeProperty.

BTW, DispatchIfNecessary is implemented as :

```
public void DispatchIfNecessary(Action action)
        {
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            else
                action.Invoke();
        }
```

Comment: Please give some more details about your callback method where you want to access property of WCF Service.

Comment: First thought, did you try to set `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant`?

Comment: yes, I've tried the Reentrant option, no joy.

Comment: So your case is more complicated as it looked at the beginning. Try adding `CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)` to the class which implements the callback.

Comment: I've tried.. [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode =         ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
   AND ....[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
   AND ..[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]  but no luck.

Comment: When using `CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)`, try also to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);` rather than synchronous version.

Comment: Genius - thanks, calling the Asynchronous BeginInvoke worked. Now, how do I mark your suggestion as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DispatchIfNecessary` use asynchronous version of `Invoke`, so your callback won't wait for finishing UI changes, that can't be done because UI thread is waiting for end of callback processing (hence we have deadlock):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```